How to change caption width in collage view?
I am trying to increase the width of a caption in Squarespace when using collage view. I can't seem to increase only the caption without the image and font sizes are increasing as well.
The real goal is that the text "Stephanie Fesneau &" to appear all on the same line, which is why I thought of increasing the width of the caption. I would not want to make the font smaller to fit it all in, but if you have any other solutions I am open.
Block ID is #block-59735afb962b7d6823ed.
Here's the HTML of the part that I would like to change (I believe):
<div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image sqs-text-ready" data-block-type="5" id="block-59735afb962b7d6823ed"><div class="sqs-block-content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1729627269553_595">    

      <figure class="sqs-block-image-figure image-block-outer-wrapper image-block-v2 design-layout-collage combination-animation-none individual-animation-none individual-text-animation-none image-position-left sqs-text-ready" data-scrolled="" data-test="image-block-v2-outer-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1729627269553_594">

        <div class="intrinsic" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1729627269553_593">
          
            <div class="
                
                image-inset" data-animation-role="image" data-description="" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1729627269553_592">
            <div class="sqs-image-shape-container-element
              
                content-fit
              
            " style="
              position: relative;
              overflow: hidden;-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
              
            " id="yui_3_17_2_1_1729627269553_591">   
              
              
              <img data-stretch="true" data-src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg" data-image="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg" data-image-dimensions="2141x1427" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="" data-load="false" elementtiming="system-image-block" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg" width="2141" height="1427" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, (max-width: 767px) 100vw, 100vw" style="display:block;object-fit: contain;" onload="this.classList.add(&quot;loaded&quot;)" srcset="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg?format=100w 100w, https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg?format=300w 300w, https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg?format=500w 500w, https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg?format=750w 750w, https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg?format=1000w 1000w, https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg?format=1500w 1500w, https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53151019e4b06a95ceb873c5/51e76151-f308-4b9b-87c7-b892ccf26349/steph+fausto.jpg?format=2500w 2500w" loading="lazy" decoding="async" data-loader="sqs" class="loaded">

              <div class="image-overlay" style="overflow: hidden;-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);"></div>
            </div>
          
            </div>
          
        </div>
       
          
          <figcaption class="image-card-wrapper" data-width-ratio="">
            <div class="image-card sqs-dynamic-text-container">

              
                <div class="image-title-wrapper"><div class="image-title sqs-dynamic-text" data-width-percentage="29.9" style="font-size: max(0.75rem, 29.9%);"><p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">STEPHANIE FESNEAU &amp;<br>FAUSTO CARPINO</p></div></div>           
            

            </div>
          </figcaption>
        

      </figure>

</div></div>
 

This is what I've tried so far (plus variations):
#block-59735afb962b7d6823ed .image-caption {
    width: 120% !important;
    left: -10%;
}

(does nothing)
#block-59735afb962b7d6823ed .sqs-block-content {
    width: 120% !important;
    font-size: initial !important;
    left: 0; 
    transform: translateX(-10%); 
}

(increases image as well, past the edge of the webpage)
.image-card {
    position: relative;
}

.image-title-wrapper {
    width: 120%;
    left: -10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-title {
    font-size: max(0.75rem, 29.9%);
}

(extends the caption but doesn't shift left, so the text gets cut off)
div#block-59735afb962b7d6823ed {
    div.image-title em {
    font-style: normal;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.image-card.sqs-dynamic-text-container {
    padding-left: 5% !important;
}
figcaption.image-card-wrapper {
    width: 60% !important;
}}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
div#block-59735afb962b7d6823ed figcaption.image-card-wrapper {
    width: 70% !important;
}}

(does nothing)

The STEPHANIE FESNEAU & part of your HTML is on one line, even before I apply any CSS. Can you please clarify, did you mean that you want this and the following text FAUSTO CARPINO to be on one line, or what exactly is the issue here? We also don't know if/what additional styling applies, before/in addition to those snippets you have shown us.

I would like STEPHANIE FESNEAU & to be on one line, and FAUSTO CARPINO to be on another line. There's a  after the '&' but when it's published on Squarespace it ends up being STEPHANIE (new line) FESNEAU & (new line) FAUSTO CARPINO, due to the width of the caption box.
